# Postfix keeping email in queue for indefinite time. Sending from sendmail its working. Any idea?

Tags: 14.04, php, postfix, mail

I have set up postfix on my ubuntu. I have configured it properly so when ever I send email through Command Line or from "Read User Mail" section of Webmin its working. But when I try sending php code its not working. It is putting that email in queue for indefinite time.

p.s. I am using different from email address in php code.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh my bad.

My receiving address has blocked this email and that's why it is not working.